# What is the compatible JQuery line of code for IE7 and IE8?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

This line of code is working fine for Firefox

```
$("#<%=txt1.ClientID%>").text()
```

but not for IE8 and IE7. See the scenario below in order to understand what I really mean:-
Scenario:-

1. Loading .aspx page.
2. populating text box with some data from database.
3. Now user changes data in same text-box at client-side (means page not yet submitted) So here in firefox, the above line of javascript is showing me the actual data came from database, but IE7&8 showing me the changed data. But I want actual data.

So i need some compatible code for IE7 & IE8

I hope i explained it well what i need. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's `txt1`? Is it an `<input>`?

Use `input.value`, or in jQuery `val()`, to read the value of a form field. `text()` reads textual content inside an element, which for most form fields is nothing.

For a `<textarea>` the textual content will be the initial contents of the field as in the source HTML file, **not** the current value of the field. (These initial contents correspond to the DOM `defaultValue` property, not `value`. In an `<input>`, this is the `value="..."` property instead of textual content, but it's still `defaultValue` in the DOM and not `value`.)

Comment: I didnt get what are you saying here. There is a difference between these two line of code (IN FIREFOX ONLY) $("#<%=txt1.ClientID%>").attr("value") and $("#<%=txt1.ClientID%>").text()
WHEN YOU CHANGE VALUE OF TEXT BOX AT CLIENT SIDE ONLY

Comment: You should not use either of those lines of code. To read a form field value, the correct jQuery method is `val()`. `attr('val')` is misleading (it's actually reading the value *property*, not the `value=""` *attribute*), and `text()` is simply wrong: it'll return the `defaultValue` property for a multi-line text box, and nothing at all for a single line text box, except on IE, where you get the `value` instead of the `defaultValue` due to bugs. Avoid all this confusion: just use `val()`.

Comment: Thanks @bobince. You got it what i really wanted to say. My requirment is if default value is changed in multi-line text box and user is leaving the page w/o saving it, it should prompt if user wants to save the change in both browsers (firefox and IE7 & IE8). What do you suggest here..?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing about that snippet that would be incompatible with any of the IEs. Maybe you have a syntax error elsewhere that's breaking your code? For example, a list or hash defined with a trailing comma is a common IE-only error, if it appears anywhere in a `<script>` block it breaks the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet will capture the contents of the textfield at the time the code is executed.

This behaviour is the same on IE7,8 and Firefox.

Make sure your code is only been run on document.ready.

Comment: @Matt: code runs after document.ready. But behavior is not same on IE7,8 and Firefox.